# How to add two dataset into rdlc to form single report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have two queries and they are different. I want to show these two queries data in rdlc.

How do I bind these two datasets?

Comment: Create One dataset with two DataTable and set the source, Here 2 datatable means two query output

Comment: please give me clear explaination. thanks